# What are the operations supported after an object is moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

If an object is actually moved to another location, what are the operations supported on the original object?

To elaborate it, I have a type `T` with available move constructor. With the following statements

```
T x{constructor-args};
T y{std::move(x)};
```

what all can be done with the object `x` (provided that the object actually moves from `x` to `y` using available move constructor of `T`)?

Specifically,

- `x` can be destroyed for sure. Can I assume `x` is trivially destructible after move?
- can `x` be assigned or move assigned to a new object ( I guess yes, as I have seen many `swap` uses this)?
- can I construct a new object object in place of `x`? If by any chance this is allowed, then is it possible to have a `uninitialized_move` which works with (partially) overlapped source & destination range, like `std::copy` and unlike `std::uninitialized_copy` ?

  ```
  T z{some-args};
  x = z; //or x = std::move(z);
  T u{some-args};
  new(&x) T{std::move(u)}; // or new(&x) T{u}; etc
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you define it to be.  At the least, the resulting
object should be destructable—its destructor will be
called, and the state of the object should be such that that
causes no problems.

The standard library guarantees that its objects are some
coherent state.  You can call any of the member functions: it is
unspecified what you get in return, *but* the results will be
coherent: if you call `size` on a vector which has been moved,
you can also call `operator[]` with an index less than the value
returned by `size` (but in the only reasonable implementation,
`size` will return 0,).  This is probably more than what is
needed for effective use, however; all that is really necessary
is that calling the destructor will work.

To make it clearer, using `std::vector` as an example: if we
suppose the usual implementation, with three pointers, begin,
end and limit (or however they are called: limit is meant to be
one past the end of the allocated memory, so that `capacity()`
returns `limit - begin`).  After moving, the standard would
require that all three pointers be null.  In most
implementations, the limit pointer will not be accessed in the
destructor, so the looser requirements of being deletable would
be met if only the begin and end pointers were set to null.

Comment: So, I assume assignment (copy & move) are allowed, and Not placement construct. Then, say given three pointers in order p1,p2,p3, where [p1,p2) is raw memory, and [p2,p3) contains some objects of type T, what is the best way to move them in the range [p1,p1+(p3-p2)) ? My guess, `uninitialized_copy` with `move_iterator` is not going to work, as some objects may get move constructed on a moved-from location.

Comment: @abir Do you want to copy them, or move them?  (But I'm not sure what your question is.)

Comment: Move the objects on [p2,p3) a few places back, starting from p1. So i guess, I have to do some combination of `uninitialized_move` and `move` depending on the raw memory [p1,p2) and memory containing moved objects [p2,p3+p1-p2) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to library types, the standard says (17.6.5.15)

> Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

This means they should, at a minimum, be destructible and assignable. As James mentions below, the object should still comply with its own interface. Your own types should follow the same idea.

You should not be using placement-new for this sort of thing. Pretend the move constructor doesn't exist and write code the same way as before, using operator=. The last line in your example should be `x=std::move(u);` or `x=u;`.

Comment: It means a lot more than that.  For example, a valid but unspecified state for `std::vector` means that if `v` has been moved, you can still call `v.size()`, `for ( size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++ i ) v[i];` must still be valid, and `v.push_back( something );` must work.  In practice, supporting this if you also support destruction is not significantly more work for `std::vector`, but for more complex types, it could make a difference.

Comment: You're right, but I'm talking about the *most general* requirements for a sensible move operator.

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly my point.  The most general requirements are less than those the standard imposes on its own types.